# How to get string at position in text node value using XSLT?

Tags: xml, string, xslt, position

I am trying to use the below XSLT to transform my XML document, and the transformation is working fine. What I need now is to be able to get the first set of numbers before the space character inside list item text node value. The purpose is to use it inside the `<doc:id>`

I have tried:

```
<xsl:template match="li">
    <document>
        <title><xsl:apply-templates/></title>

        <location>


            <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://localhost/auto/teo',mydoc)"></xsl:value-of>
           <test>
               <xsl:for-each select="text()[1]">
                   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </xsl:for-each>

           </test>
        </location>
            <extension >

                  <doc:id>

                      <xsl:number value="position()" format="01" />
                    </doc:id>

            </extension>
        </document>
</xsl:template>
```

And here is the source document for transformation:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- This is my first comment -->
 <ol>
    <li>1 data</li>
    <li>2 data</li>
    <li>3 data</li>
    <li>4 data</li>
    <li>5 data</li>
    <li>6 data</li>
    <li>7 data</li>
    <li>8 data</li>
    <li>9 data</li>
    <li>10 data</li>
    <li>11 data</li>
    <li>12 data</li>
    <li>13 data</li>
 </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you expecting for output, and what did you actually see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
<doc:id>
   <xsl:number value="substring-before(., ' ')" format="01" />
</doc:id>
```

Comment: How can we get the last substring?

Comment: I tried the following and it worked fine <xsl:variable name="lastsr" select="tokenize(., '\s+')[last()]" />